# O(1) reverse string

Tags: c++, string, recursion

Is this the best way to reverse a string in c++?

```
void reverseString(string &str) {

int begin = 0;
int end = str.length() - 1;

while (begin < end)
    swap(str[begin++], str[end--]);
}
```

Is there a better way using recursion?

Comment: [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Comment: If you access the string with reverse iterators, you have ... O(0)? If you wrap the string into a class which automatically uses forward or reverse iteration depending on an internal flag, reverse would reduce to changing the flag. That would be O(1).

Comment: If you must reverse the string in memory, how could that possibility be O(1)? You'll need to access all n elements.

Comment: Ok, so I'm curious, if i were asked in an interview to write a function that reversed a string, would the above answer be viewed as acceptable/good or bad? Sorry, it's 3 am and i can hardly think.

Comment: Note this algorithm may not work for empty strings. Function length returns an unsigned integer. If empty, 0 - 1 gives you a huge positive integer. If this is larger than the max value of an int, casting it to int is undefined behavior (meaning that the program may crash, give you an incorrect result or the expected one).

Comment: @PaulEvans Actually, we *could* make it `O(1)` (according to the definition of) - we just need to limit string length to some fix N_MAX...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel, there are efficient algorithms that you can easily use without recreating them.

As other people said, to reverse a string, or really any STL container `std::reverse()` is the best option.

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
int main() 
{ 
    std::string foo("foo"); 
    std::string copy(foo); 
    std::cout << foo << '\n' << copy << '\n'; 
    std::reverse(copy.begin(), copy.end()); 
    std::cout << foo << '\n' << copy << '\n'; 
}
```

Also, you might want to use a copy of the string as in the example above because `std::reverse()` actions in place.

Comment: Have a look at possible implementation on cppreference.com [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse). I doubt that the std library does this more efficient than the approach of OP (except it would obtain any platform specific hardware "magic"). IMHO, this is O(n) if you consider individual char write operations.

Comment: as OP seems to be seeking for best complexity/performance you could also mention traversing the string via reverse iterators. The most optimal way to do something is to not do it at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

A string is by definition arbitrary length, which makes any algorithm that accesses its elements O(*N*) at a minimum.

So O(*1*) is impossible.

Your O(*N*) approach is the best you can get (`std::reverse` does exactly the same as what you have).. Recursion won't help (in fact will only make things worse).

---

Unrelated note: your code has a couple of potential bugs:

```
int end = str.length() - 1;
```

1. that will overflow when `str.length()` is `0` (undefined behavior until C++20)
2. an `int` will overflow when `str.length()` is >2 GB